# Need to mock one service method only in an integration test

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking, integration-testing

I am writing grails integration tests which call out to a controller which call a service which calls another service which calls another service.

```
Controller -> ServiceA.method1()  -> ServiceB.method2() -> ServiceC.method3()
```

the last method in the last service to be called (`ServiceC.method3()`) makes a call to the outside world (another JVM) and returns a result, which I want to mock out for my integration test.  So I am still testing the chain up to and back from that particular service method.

I was reading up on mocking in grails but it seems that it is only possible in unit testing.

Any tips how to progress this one?

Comment: Tips: 1. Beans are auto wired in integration test. 2. `metaClass` can be used to add/mock behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the metaClass to override a method's functionality. I do this all the time in my integration tests as my way to mock.

So in your test method do something like this (note that the method arg types must match exactly with the real method):

```
controller.serviceA.serviceB.serviceC.metaClass.method3 = { Args args ->
    // do whatever you want here, set flags to indicate method called,
    // assert args, declare return types, etc
    // return 'mocked' result
}
```

Make sure in your integration test tear down method you reset the metaClass of this service otherwise all your other int tests will have the same definition:

```
controller.serviceA.serviceB.serviceC.metaClass = null
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was reading up on mocking in grails but it seems that it is only
>   possible in unit testing.

That's certainly not true. 
You could use all ways of mocking that are available in Groovy in both unit and integration tests.

With mocking using Map coercion, it can be this easy:

```
controller.serviceA.serviceB.serviceC = [method3: {return 'MockValue'}] as ServiceC
```